# how to press the certain button in webbrowser?

Tags: c#

there are 20 buttons on the site with the same names and class. I saw on the Form1 the webbrowser and button component. what I need to do to press first time the button with the pressing first four buttons on the site, the second press - next four buttons and etc.? when I try to do that I have 20 buttons selected at once:

```
HtmlElementCollection elmCol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
var asd = elmCol[0];
foreach (HtmlElement elmBtn in elmCol)
{
    if (elmBtn.GetAttribute("className") == "item streamItem streamItem-user")
    {
        elmBtn.Focus();
        elmBtn.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
}
```

Comment: The className property isn't unique enough, do the buttons specify an id attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a class to the group of buttons you need to press.

i.e:

```
<button class="button-group-1 item streamItem streamItem-user">
<button class="button-group-1 item streamItem streamItem-user">
<button class="button-group-2 item streamItem streamItem-user">
<button class="button-group-2 item streamItem streamItem-user">
```

This way you can test to which group the button belongs and press it if needed

```
//Will click the buttons which belong to the first group
if (elmBtn.GetAttribute("className") == "button-group-1 item streamItem streamItem-user")
{
    elmBtn.Focus();
    elmBtn.InvokeMember("Click");
}
```